# How can I check the checkbox when the DataGrid item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid data item that is automatically generated. I add a rowheader and bind it to the isselected field in the datagridrow data

```
<DataGrid
            hc:DataGridAttach.CanUnselectAllWithBlankArea="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
            HeadersVisibility="All"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Print_Infos}"
            RowHeaderWidth="60">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Item.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

How can I select the checkbox in the rowheader when I select datagridrow?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer instead of an edit to the original question.

Comment: @mm8 I got it, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved

```
<DataGrid
        hc:DataGridAttach.CanUnselectAllWithBlankArea="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
        HeadersVisibility="All"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Print_Infos}"
        RowHeaderWidth="60">
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}" TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Item.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Just add a Setter to DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle and bind a value